# Map One Column of a Table with Hibernate Annotation

Tags: hibernate, join

I work on a private network so too difficult to copy and paste my code.  I have found a bunch of answers close to what I need but none have worked out.  I'll try to do a quick example of my code, hopefully good enough to decipher my problem.

```
@Table(name="DRIVER")
class Driver {
    long id; //ID - primary key of Driver
    String driverIdentStr;  // DRIVER_IDENT_STR - like driver's license #
}//end class Driver

@Table(name="GROUP_PARTICIPANT")
class GroupParticipant {
    long id; //ID - primary key of GroupParticipant
    long driverId; //DRIVER_ID - id of the Driver participanting and maps to Driver.id

    //I just want this one value from Driver and not the whole Driver...
    //I've tried:
    //@Formula("(select driverIdentStr from Driver where Driver.id = DRIVER_ID)")
    //also tried:
    //@Column(table="DRIVER", name="driverIdentStr")
    String driverIdentStr;  
}//end class GroupParticipant
```

The @Formula failed with "table or view not found" but i definitely have a Driver class defined mapping to DRIVER table.  When I changed the query language in the @Formula to be SQL instead of HQL Hibernate complains that GROUPPARTICIPANT0.driverIdentStr is an invalid identifier - think it was trying to retrieve driverIdentStr from GroupParticipant instead of getting the value from Driver (??).

The @Column fails, i think, because i'm not sure how to map to DRIVER from the driverId I have in GroupParticipant.

Bottom line, i can't figure out how to get GroupParticipant.driverIdentStr to be pulled from joining GroupParticipant.driverId on Driver.id and getting Driver.driverIdentStr.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what worked...

@Formula("(select d.DRIVER_IDENT_STR from DRIVER d where d.ID = DRIVER_ID)")

I found the answer at:
http://gokhan.ozar.net/hibernate-derived-properties-formula-annotation
under "A more complex example" heading.

Here is what I learned from reading and from the example...

1. Only SQL in Formula annotation (no HQL at all)
2. Before finding the example above, I used **d.** in the WHERE but not in the SELECT part of the Formula query and Hibernate complained. At that point, I thought Hibernate was ignoring my Formula annotation and trying to get the value from the primary table but it was not ignoring my Formula, my Formula was essentially telling it to get the value from the primary table (because **d.** not used to tell it otherwise.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `@Formula` annotation is interpreted as a SQL fragment, so the following should work, assuming standard naming based on your mappings:

```
@Formula("SELECT driverIdentStr FROM DRIVER WHERE id = driverId")
```

To clarify:

1. `driverIdentStr` is the column name in entity `Driver` that is mapped to that property.
2. `id` is the primary key column name in entity `Driver`.
3. `driverId` is the column name in `GroupParticipant` .
4. I used the explicit table name `DRIVER` in the event your database is case sensitive.